# Manipulating vectors inside class methods

Tags: c++

I just started learning about vectors, and they seem really handy, if talking about lists from a file. But I'm having a problem while trying to return a new vector from a class method and put it to another method of the same class.

i.e.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    string name;
    string age;
};

class Test
{
    string name;
    string age;
public:
    void get(vector<A> students)
    {
        vector<A> specificStudents;
        //rewrite a couple of students from vector<A>students
        //to vector<A> specificStudents
    };
    void set(vector<A> specificStudents)
    {
        //I need to get vector<A> specificStudents here
    };
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> students;
    A stud;

    ifstream file("file.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < file.eof(); i++)
    {
        getline(file, stud.name);
        getline(file, stud.age);
        students.push_back(stud);
    };
    Test test;
    test.get(students);

    return 0;
}
```

Can I return it as a function argument?

Comment: "Can I return it" - yes, of course you can.

Comment: When I tried doing that I got a fatal error, which I didn't understand at all, or function returned value 0... so how can i do that?

Comment: If you got a specific error message, you should include it in the question. Returning a vector is easy, for example`std::vector<int> f() { std::vector<int> v; v.push_back(666); return v; }`

Comment: Then show us the broken code and the error. We can't help you if we can't see those things. There's no point showing us some other code, and no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear, but do you want to save a copy of `students` inside `test`?:

```
class Test
{
    vector<A> specificStudents;
public:
    const vector<A>& get() const
    {
        return specificStudents;
    }
    void set(const vector<A>& students)
    {
        specificStudents = students;
        // maybe modify `specificStudents` here in some way or assign it differently
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> students;
    A stud;

    ifstream file("file.txt");
    while (getline(file, stud.name) && getline(file, stud.age))
    {
        students.push_back(stud);
    }
    Test test;
    test.set(students);

    //... Do something with test

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't know yet what `&` and `const` mean in this, you can just remove them (until you learn about them).

You seem to have gotten `get` and `set` mixed up. By usual convention, `get` *gets* something stored in the class object to the caller and `set` *sets* something in the class object (with a value provided by the caller).

---

I also fixed your input loop. I don't know what you thought `file.eof()` does, but comparing to `i` does not do anything useful.

---

Also be aware of where `;` belongs and where it doesn't. It belongs after single statements and class definitions, but not after `}` of function definitions or other statement blocks, such as the one of `while`.

Answer (score 1):

YES, you can return vector from a function.

To do this you can write a function like this one:

```
std::vector<A> get(vector<A> students)
```

and the inside it return the vector. An example can be:

```
 vector<A> get(vector<A> students)
    {
        vector<A> specificStudents;
        //rewrite a couple of students from vector<A>students
        //to vector<A> specificStudents
        return specificStudents;

    };
```